# Como fazer esse formulario de email em C#?

Tags: c#, formulário

Estou começando agora a trabalhar com o padrão MVC asp.net, eu criei um view para contatos e nela inserir um formulário que ao ser preenchido e clicado no botão enviar irá para o meu email, portanto eu fiz apenas o frontend e não sei como fazer o restante, alguém poderia me mostra como isso é feito? Abaixo o código do meu form:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contact";
}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="w3-container w3-content w3-padding-64" style="max-width:800px">
    <h2 class="w3-wide w3-center">CONTATO</h2>
    <p class="w3-opacity w3-center"><i>Dúvidas? Contacte nosso suporte!</i></p>
    <div class="w3-row w3-padding-32">
        <div class="w3-col m6 w3-large w3-margin-bottom">
            <i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="width:30px"></i> São Gabriel da Palha, ES<br>
            <i class="fa fa-phone" style="width:30px"></i> Phone: 27 000 000 000<br>
            <i class="fa fa-envelope" style="width:30px"> </i> Email: ebase@ebase.com.br<br>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-col m6">
            <form action="#" target="_blank">
                <div class="w3-row-padding" style="margin:0 -16px 8px -16px">
                    <div class="w3-half">
                        <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Nome" required name="Nome">
                    </div>
                    <div class="w3-half">
                        <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Email" required name="Email">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Mensagem" required name="Mensagem">
                <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-section w3-right" type="submit">ENVIAR</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Você quer essa página para estar dentro do e-mail, é isso?

Comment: @GabrielColetta a minha dúvida é, como eu vou chamar a função de envio através do botão enviar? Como eu farei a ação desse botão?? Em PHP já fiz isso muitas vezes, mais em C# será a primeira... Você conseguiu me entender agora????

Comment: Pesquise um pouco, há varios tutoriais ensinando a enviar email usando C#. pela sua pergunta, parece que vc nem ao menos tentou fazer antes de perguntar.

Comment: Eu sei como faz para enviar cara, eu não sei como fazer a ação do botão ENVIAR, é apenas isso que eu gostaria de saber!

Comment: Não consegui entender... você não tem uma Action e uma Controller para receber esse formulário? Não sabe como colocar em `<form action="#"`? Não sabe como fazer post via Ajax? Ou não sabe como se envia um e-mail em C#? (o que não tem nada a ver com esse formulário)

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Pronto sem querer você respondeu, o que eu preciso fazer é colocar um action no form passando o arquivo que contem os comandos para o envio do email!!!

Comment: @WPfan não é o arquivo, é a rota que você deve passar.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo exemplifique por favor!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para exemplificar, digamos que essa view é retornada pela action `Contatos()` na `HomeController`. Crie um overload para `Contatos()` recebendo os parâmetros `nome`, `email` e `mensagem` adicionando a anotação `[HttpPost]`

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Contatos()
    {
        //Aqui retorna sua view com o o formulário
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Contatos(string nome, string email, string mensagem)
    {
        //Faça validação adicional nos seus parâmetros de entrada
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nome)&& !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email)&&!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mensgem))
        {
            //implemente o seu script para enviar o e-mail utilizando os parâmetros recebidos
            //ou chame o método que envia, caso você já tenha o feito
        }
        //Vai retornar para sua Contatos com o verbo [HttpGet]
        return View();
    }
```

Já na sua view onde está o formulário você direciona o post para Action que você criou com o verbo `[HttpPost]`

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Contatos","Home")" method="post">`
```

Isso não é apenas para enviar e-mail, é uma prática comum do MVC para as soluções de CRUD. Não obstante, você ainda poderia criar uma `ViewModel` como além de ser uma boa prática, irá trazer muitos benefícios e qualidade para a sua solução.

A implementação mais simples seria como o exemplo abaixo:

```
public class ContatoViewModel
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Mensagem { get; set; }
}
```

E a sua Action pode receber os parâmetros da seguinte forma:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Contatos(ContatoViewModel contato)
{
   //...
}
```

Mas enriquecendo a `ContatoViewModel` com `DataAnnotations` e declarando ela como a `Model` de sua `View` e aproveitando os `Helpers` é que a brincadeira fica divertida.

```
public class ContatoViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Nome: ", ShortName = "Nome")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Informe o seu nome")]
    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "O seu nome deve possuir ao menos 3 caracteres")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "O seu nome deve possuir no máximo 50 caracteres")]        
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Display(Name= "E-mail: ", ShortName = "E-mail")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Informe o seu E-mail")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "E-mail inválido")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name= "Mensagem: ", ShortName = "Mensagem" )]
    [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = "A sua mensagem deve possuir no máximo 200 caracteres.")]        
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Escreva sua mensgem")]        
    public string Mensagem { get; set; }
}
```

Adicionando enriquecendo sua controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Contatos()
{            
    var model= new ContatoViewModel();
    //Enviando a ContatoViewModel como Model da sua View
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
//Muito importante para tentar garantir que o post foi feito exclusivamente da sua view
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]  
public ActionResult Contatos(ContatoViewModel contato)
{
    var model = new ContatoViewModel();

    //Validação obtida atráves das regras declaradas na ViewModel
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model = contato;                                
    }
    else
    {
        //implemente o seu script para enviar o e-mail utilizando os parâmetros recebidos
        //ou chame o método que envia, caso você já tenha o feito

    }

    return View(model);
}
```

E usufruindo dos Helpers em sua View:

```
@{
    @model seu.namespace.ContatoViewModel
}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="w3-container w3-content w3-padding-64" style="max-width:800px">
    <h2 class="w3-wide w3-center">CONTATO</h2>
    <p class="w3-opacity w3-center"><i>Dúvidas? Contacte nosso suporte!</i></p>
    <div class="w3-row w3-padding-32">
        <div class="w3-col m6 w3-large w3-margin-bottom">
            <i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="width:30px"></i> São Gabriel da Palha, ES<br>
            <i class="fa fa-phone" style="width:30px"></i> Phone: 27 000 000 000<br>
            <i class="fa fa-envelope" style="width:30px"> </i> Email: ebase@ebase.com.br<br>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-col m6">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Contatos", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="w3-row-padding" style="margin:0 -16px 8px -16px">
                    <div class="w3-half">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Nome, new { @class = "w3-input w3-border" })                
                    </div>
                    <div class="w3-half">                        
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "w3-input w3-border"})                
                    </div>
                </div>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Mensagem, new { @class = "w3-input w3-border" })


                <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-section w3-right" type="submit">ENVIAR</button>
                <br />
                <div>
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito cara, tudo certo

Comment: Adicionei algumas informações complementares para você entender melhor outros recursos do MVC e partindo daí, acredito que você terá uma base para seguir seus estudos.

Comment: Muito bom cara, você tem um grande conhecimento, eu to iniciando agora com MVC asp.net... trabalhava antes com PHP dai to meio perdido hehehehe